# crawler is not crawling second start_url

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape movie-reviews and tv-news from hindustantimes.com. When i'm running this code it is only scraping the first start_url but it's not able to scrape the second start_url. I think the counter has to be reset but I'm not able to find out how. I want to scrape the n numbers of pages from both the start_url.

```py
import scrapy
#test_push
from..items import HindustantimesItem

class HindustantimesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Hindustantimes_review'
    page_number = 2
    count = 0

    def start_requests(self): 

        urls = ['https://www.hindustantimes.com/movie-reviews/page/?pageno={}',
        'https://www.hindustantimes.com/tv/page/?pageno={}',
        ]
        ur = []
        for url in urls:
            for i in range(1,3):
                x = url.format(i)
                yield scrapy.Request(url=x, callback=self.parse,)

    def parse(self, response):
        print("-------^^^^^^---------")
        print(response.request.url)
        items = {}


        with open('output.txt', 'a') as the_file:
            the_file.write(response.request.url)
            the_file.write( "\n")

        title_xpath = ['//*[@id="scroll-container"]/ul/li[{}]/div/div[2]/div/a/text()', '/html/body/div[1]/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[{}]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/text()']
        page_review_xpath = ['//*[@id="scroll-container"]/ul/li[{}]/div/div[2]/p/text()','/html/body/div[1]/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[{}]/div/div[2]/div[2]/text()']
        page_link_xpath = ['//*[@id="scroll-container"]/ul/li[{}]/div/div[2]/div/a/@href', '/html/body/div[1]/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[{}]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/@href']
        if HindustantimesSpider.count ==0:
            current_title_xpath = title_xpath[0]
            current_review_xpath = page_review_xpath[0]
            current_link_xpath = page_link_xpath[0]
            HindustantimesSpider.count+=1
        else:
            current_title_xpath = title_xpath[1]
            current_review_xpath = page_review_xpath[1]
            current_link_xpath = page_link_xpath[1]

        count = response.xpath(current_title_xpath.format("*")).getall()
        count = len(count)
        i = 1
        while i<=count:
            outputs = HindustantimesItem()
            outputs['page_title'] = response.xpath(current_title_xpath.format(i)).get()
            outputs['review_content'] = response.xpath(current_review_xpath.format(i)).get()
            outputs['review_link'] = response.xpath(current_link_xpath.format(i)).get()
            i+=1
            fl = 0
            if outputs['page_title'] == []:
                outputs['page_title'] = ''
                fl+=1
            if outputs['review_content'] == []:
                outputs['review_content'] = ''
                fl+=1
            if outputs['review_link'] == []:
                outputs['review_link'] = ''
                fl += 1
            else:
                if 'Review:' in outputs['page_title'].split(" ") or 'review:' in outputs['page_title'].split(" "):
                    yield outputs

        pass
```

Comment: What is the output when it starts to crawl?

Comment: page 1 output is not coming as i put the two xpath 1st is for 1st page for both url and 2nd xpath is for page number 2 onwards for both the url

Comment: As I can see from your code, there are several problems in it. When the spider starts to crawl, it prints the event in output. Reading the output can help you to understand your code problems and help us to see what happened there.

Answer (score 0):

```
def start_requests(self): 

        urls = ['https://www.hindustantimes.com/movie-reviews/page/?pageno={}',
        'https://www.hindustantimes.com/tv/page/?pageno={}',
        ]
        ur = []
        for url in urls:
            for i in range(1,3):
                x = url.format(i)
                yield scrapy.Request(url=x, callback=self.parse,dont_filter=True)
```

Comment: see page number 1st has different xpath for both the url and from page number 2 its has different xpath. and im getting the output from page 2 not getting page 1 output.